# Nokogiri web scraping problems?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize, watir

I want to web scrape from [example](http://www.parkers.co.uk/), just to play around with nokogiri gem's capabilities.

So I am stuck at the moment basically in the beginning of all:

How can I fill in information in `Select` field with nokogiri and then loop through first select field "Select manufacturer" and then loop through second select field "Select model" and push Go/OK button every time in loop?

Comment: Do I need to use watir? Or mechanize for this ? I heard that this can be solved with PhantomJs / CasperJs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokogiri is for parsing HTML content. It's not for filling out forms and navigating websites. If the website is pure HTML (no JavaScript), then Mechanize (+ Nokogiri) is what you want to use.

Mechanize is for filling out forms and navigation, and then you can use Nokogiri to parse the resulting content.

If there's JavaScript then you probably want to use Watir and perhaps PhantomJS, which enables you to run a headless browser.

Comment: Google these terms "watir examples" and "ruby mechanize examples", that will get you started. And start with a simple webpage until you get the hang of it.